# What are the advantages of using a ring flash for portraits?

Tags: lighting, portrait, ring-flash

I have a Ray Flash ring flash that I got for macro work. Whenever I mention it to a photographer, they often say that they really like it for portrait work.

What are the advantages of using a ring flash for portrait photography?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The advantages when used as a main/only light include:

- your work resembles big budget fashion photography from the 80s (when ringlights were used extensively)
- you get a crisp detailed look without the big shadows you'd get from a point source. By surrounding the lens you light from all angles simultaneously you eliminate strong shadows, leaving only a faint shadow which encircles your subject. Here's a comparison I shot between a ringlight and regular on camera flash:

[image]

- you get cool circular catchlights
- setup is easy with few settings to adjust.

There are disadvantages too, unlike a softbox the light is unforgiving of blemishes etc.

The ringlight can also be used more subtly in a multi light setup to improve definition by throwing light into shadow areas.

Comment: Also worth noting that it often tends to produce rather washed out looking colors (an effect your example also shows quite nicely).

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: you're right. Is that because of the lack of shadows?

Comment: @Craig: no -- at least not mostly. Most of it is that with the light so close to the lens, you get a lot of specular highlights reflecting white light directly back toward the lens. Moving the light farther off-axis lets you see the diffuse light more.

Comment: Do you just like grab a model and you're like "Hey, I need to take your picture two different ways for a website?"

Comment: @rfusca Yeah, pretty much.

Answer (score 1):

Ring flash gives a very distinctive look. It virtually eliminates shadows on the face of the subject (ring flash shots are usually taken head-on) while leaving a soft, even shadow around the subject.